# Script to run a jupyter notebook automatically

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook with both html and python code in it. Is it possible to write a script that will launch the notebook and run it in the browser? Most solutions on the web refer to running these scripts from the command line, but I want them to show up on the

Comment: Isn't this what the `file_to_run` traitlet is for from http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what OS you're on, but here's a small batch file that moves into my directory with my .ipynb files, starts Jupyter, and then opens a specific notebook of mine:

```
cd "%userprofile%\desktop\att"
start chrome.exe http://localhost:8888/notebooks/ATT_SQL.ipynb#
jupyter notebook
```

I just put this on my desktop and double click it to start Jupyter. Just replace your notebook's name where mine is `ATT_SQL.ipynb#`. You'll also have to change the `cd` command as well.

Edit:
Or better yet:

```
cd %userprofile%\path\to\your\jupyter\dir
jupyter notebook yourNotebook.ipynb
```

[Source](https://kb.brandeis.edu/display/SCI/How+to+open+a+notebook+file+with+iPython+notebook)

Answer (score 0):

here is the coding in the batch file i use:
(example.bat)

```
@echo on

call C:\Users\J\anaconda3\Scripts\activate C:\Users\J\anaconda3\

cd "C:\Users\J\Zeitgeist\Processing Files\SpyderVision\Daily Run Files\"

ipython -c  "%run Module6-Final_Analysis.ipynb"

pause
```

### (example.bat)

```
"call" = anaconda directory
"cd" = file directory
```